# How to prove that $p$ does not divide $2^{p} - 1$?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

(Note that this question is an edited version of a previous question, which I cannot delete because answers have been submitted.)

Suppose $p$ is an odd prime.

How does one prove that $p$ does not divide $2^{p} - 1$?

Comment: How would 2 divide an odd prime ever? 

Comment: Prime numbers in general have rather few factors.

Comment: For  $p>2$ $2^{p-1}>p$ and already by this simple reason cannot divide it.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown And odd numbers in general have few even factors.

Comment: I suspect you want to ask about $p$ not dividing $2^{p-1}$, and not vice versa.

Comment: Did you mean $2^{p - 1} - 1$ or $2^{p - 1} + 1$ rather than $2^{p - 1}$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes. This is what I meant. I've edited my question.

Comment: The edited question is still trivial: the only prime divisor of a power of $2$ is $2$.

Comment: Your correction makes no sense. It should be $2^p−1$, rather than $2^{p−1}$ unless you are looking for a proof that an odd number cannot divide a power of 2.

Comment: @user355705 Fine. I'll change it.

Answer (score 3):

Since $p$ is odd it is not divisible by $2$ and so by transitivity it is not divisible by $2^{p-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

it is $$2^{p-1}$$ and even number (product of factors $2$) and $$p$$ is an odd number.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (now you've finally stabilised the question): [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) tells you that $p$ does divide $2^p - 2$.